# equivalent of +[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:] for CFStringRef

Tags: objective-c, c, core-foundation

I wonder what would be an equivalent of
`+[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:]` in CoreFoundation?

I know I could use the `(__bridge NSString *)` thing this time I rather complicate my life a bit and learn a bit how was this done before Cocoa came out ... :)

To my taste is ugly to have a couple of line in objective-c to make a thing

```
...
CFErrorRef error = NULL;
CFURLRef fileURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(bundle,
                                           CFSTR("file"),
                                           CFSTR("txt"),
                                           NULL);

// Ugly piece of objc code in my whole C source file :(
NSError *nsError = (__bridge NSError *)(error);
NSString *nsString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:(__bridge NSURL *)fileURL
                                          usedEncoding:NULL
                                                 error:&nsError];

CFStringRef fileContents = (__brigde CFStringRef)nsString; 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

```
CFStringCreateFromExternalRepresentation
```

I would imagine the code being like so,

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:<path to your file>]
CFStringRef string = CFStringCreateFromExternalRepresentation(NULL, (CFDataRef)data, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

Ideally to have access to the error, you can also use NSData's dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error:

Comment: This is almost what I want ... although `-stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:` will try to guess the encoding of the file while I have to pass the encoding to `CFStringCreateFromExternalRepresentation()` big deal when reading file without knowing the encoding :(

Comment: Could try iterating multiple `CFStringCreateExternalRepresentation` with different encodings set and specify the `lossByte` to 0 so the function returns `NULL` if it can't use the encoding. I'll edit my answer if this helps! :)